# An axiomatizable not axiomatized theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, recursion

I am struggling for the first time with the incompleteness theorem and similar stuff. I know that a theory is axiomatizable if it is equivalent to an axiomatized one, which means that the set of theorem of this latter one is decidable.

My question is: are there axiomatizable but not axiomatized theories? That is: can I find at least one theory in which the set of theorems is not decidable, but can be translated into a theory with a computable set of theorems?

Thank you in advance or your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the concept you refer to as "axiomatized" is what in my experience is usually called "*recursively* axiomatized" or "axiomatic". However, the definition of that is not that *the set of theorems* is decidable, but that *the set of axioms* is decidable.

In that case, an example of a recursively *axiomatizable* but not actually recursively *axiomatized* theory (over the language consisting of a single unary predicate $p$) could be
$$ T=\{ \underbrace{p(x)\land p(x)\land\cdots\land p(x)}_{n\text{ conjuncts}} \mid n\text{ is the Gödel number of a true formula about the integers} \} $$
This theory is *equivalent* to the theory with a single axiom $p(x)$ (which is plainly recursively axiomatized), but it is not actually decidable whether or not a given formula is an *axiom* of $T$.

Comment: yes you are right, I am sorry for my mistake...thank you very much! I was trying to search an example among the many mathematical theories such as theory of cyclic rings, theory of finite modules, Peano arithmetic, and so on. but this example is perfect, I grabbed the concept.